# Not able to navigate to another Component - Angular

Tags: angular, routerlink

I have 3 component from 1st moving to 2nd. But from 2nd I am not able to navigate 3rd component.

`Name` showing only hyperlink but when clicking nothing happens.

This is 2nd component code

```
<table>
<tr *ngFor="let lst of devices; let i = index" border="1">
  <td>{{lst.DeviceId}}</td>
  <td>{{lst.LastJobStatus}}</td>
  <td> <a routerLink="deviceapps">{{lst.Name}}</a> </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

`App-routing.module.ts` class

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'devicelist/:id', component: DeviceListComponent } ,
  {path: 'deviceapps',component: DeviceAppsComponent}
];
```

3rd component code

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router, ParamMap } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-device-apps',
  templateUrl: './device-apps.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./device-apps.component.css']
})
export class DeviceAppsComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Comment: Any error in console ?

Comment: Is it the same with that ? `<a [routerLink]="['/deviceapps']">Name</a>`

Comment: @SameerKhan - Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'devicelist/96/deviceapps'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are using relative paths inside, so try to write absolute routing like:

```html
<a [routerLink]="'/deviceapps'">{{lst.Name}}</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use square bracket

```
 <a [routerLink]="'/path'">
    {{lst.Name}}
 </a>
```